# Article view with links to other articles

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, blocks, navigation

So I'm trying to create a view which displays the most recent article belonging to a specific taxonomy term and pulls out just the links to other articles which have the same term.

I want to display the article content and below that 4-5 links to other articles of the same taxonomy. I want to display this view as a block.

Is this possible? How can this be done?

Comment: And exclude the article shown in the view, this can be done with contextual filters but I forgot how.

Answer (score 0):

Add a  contextual filter: Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth), for displaying related articles