# View: How to make a list of article(in a block) related to the taxonomy term of my main article

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I would like to display a list of link in a block that are related to the taxonomy term of my main article.

I read others subjects like [article-view-with-links-to-other-articles](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36175/article-view-with-links-to-other-articles)

but it doesn't work for me. My URL is like that : **example.com/product/[node:id]** (Maybe it doesn't work because i don't have the term id in my url)

My article has a vocabulary call "tendance", this article is tag with the term, for instance "tendance one". I would like to have all the article tag with "tendance one"

I have this configuration:

1. **Contextual filter:** Content nid
2. **WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE :** raw value from URL
3. I add validation etc.
4. And in **More** section, i click on exclude

So i had a list of all my article in my block thanks to the **exclude** but there are not related to the term "tendance one" of my main article.

I tried to add relationship :

- Content: Taxonomy terms on node (and i select my vocabulary "tendance" and required relationship)
- Taxonomy term: Content using tendance

And it doesn't work, i always have the same list of article linked to the good vacabulary but not to the good term.

Do i have to pass in my url the taxonomy term to make it work?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've just found the perfect solution for me.

I tried a lot of solution with some php code but without success.

The problem was : I had one view which display an article (with a taxonomy vocabulary) and i wanted to add a block with a list of link of another content type who are linked with the same taxonomy term.

URL: www.example/product/[nid]/[title]

***Contextual filter***

1. **Contextual filter**: Content nid
2. **WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE** :  raw value from URL (path -> 2 to retrieve the node id)

***RELATIONSHIPS***

1. Content: Taxonomy terms on node (with Require this relationship)
2. (term) Taxonomy term: Content with term  (with Require this relationship) -> Relationship -> Taxonomy terms on node

And after you have to come back to the contextual filters:

- And add a **Relationship** to **Taxonomy term: Content with term**

Now it works great, i have all my other content type with the same term of taxonomy linker to the term of the main article display by view on my page.